# One icon, different colors in PHP

Tags: php, image, hue

Ok, so I have one image called `icon.png`

Its red.

It outputs as `<img src='icon.png'>`

I have columns from a table, with id's.
I want to use those id's to fluctuate the HUE of the image.

So that it will output different colors for each user.

I know of other ways I can do this, but want to know if I can just use a simple HUE adjustment based on the id number to do it.

I want the output to be...

```
User 1 <img src='icon.png'>  //This will display red
User 3 <img src='icon.png'>  //This will display slightly different
User 5 <img src='icon.png'>  //This will display slightly different again
```

All using the same image.
But using PHP's built in image manipulation features.

Anybody got ideas how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: You'd be better off pre-rendering 256 icons for each potential hue value and then simply inserting the source URL for that icon based on whatever logic you devise.

Comment: Yeah thats what I figured would be the best way, just wanted to know if there was an 'on the fly' method.....but the pre-rendering way would obviously be more efficient.

Comment: you wouldn't want to generate each hue on the fly. that'd be a massive load on your server. just pregenerate all 256 possible versions and refer to them as needed.

Comment: The "on the fly" method would be 99% the same as the pre-computed anyway, just more wasteful with CPU resources.

Comment: Yeah, thats the way Ill go , thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. The browser will cache the image upon loading the first instance, and then use it for the following instances.

Edit:

Your best bet is to simply create all of the images. This will also save CPU cycles for other more important tasks. e.g:

```
/media/icons/icon_FFAA00.png
/media/icons/icon_FFBB00.png
/media/icons/icon_FFCC00.png
```

etc..